# CategoryManyToManyField tuns to emty QuerySet in non edit mode

Tags: django-cms

I write a new plugin for `aldryn_newsblog` application. I want to list articles by categories. The plugin takes the list of categories using `CategoryManyToManyField`.

The plugin displays the articles having  requested categories only in edit mode. As soon as I publish page with newly added plugin it displays none of the articles. I checked that  `self.categories.all()` becomes empty.

Why it is happening?
This is for;

```
aldryn-newsblog2.1.1
Django==1.11.17
django-cms==3.5.3
```

It acts the same on local django development server and on remote apache

```
class NewsBlogCategoryPlugin(PluginEditModeMixin, AdjustableCacheModelMixin, NewsBlogCMSPlugin):
        ....
        categories = CategoryManyToManyField('aldryn_categories.Category', verbose_name=_('categories'), blank=True)
        ....
        def get_articles(self, request):

            print (self.categories.all())
            queryset = Article.objects
            main_qs = queryset.all().filter(categories = 
                self.categories.all())
            return main_qs
```

Comment: Are the articles published?

Comment: Yes articles were published

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is this:

- when your page is published, the plugin instance is copied
- in the published version of the page, there is now a *new* plugin instance
- this new plugin instance does not have the relations to the `Categories` that the original did

You need to ensure that when a plugin is copied, so are its relations.

See [handling relations](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations) in the django CMS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Daniele. I just have added following the [handling-relations](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations)

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.categories = oldinstance.categories.all()
```

And now it works

Comment: Glad to hear @oleg-rud  -  If that solves the issue, please mark the answer as answered, so that others can benefit.